# Translation to Russian: "The doctor would not take any gifts from the poor."

Tags: перевод

I saw this on taboeba.org and it seems wrong to me:

```
Доктор не должен брать подарков у небогатых людей.
```

I'd translate the given Russian as:

```
The doctor must not take gifts from the poor.
```

Since there is the notion of past continuous action (would not take) here wouldn't this be more accurate: (?)

```
Доктор не брал подарков у небогатых людей.
```

Comment: The first translation is wrong. The translation you assume to be accurate ("Доктор не брал подарков от небогатых людей.") is the correct one. But, I think, your question is offtopic here (no translations!).

Comment: "Would not take" is no way a "past continuous action", "would not take" is Future-Indefinite-in-the-Past Tense. The Russian sentence is in the Present, all the speculations of yours are wrong, except for the first translation into English, which is quite right. And what on earth is taboeba.org??? There's no such a site. Adequacy is what we need here.

Comment: Please reformulate this question so that it does not ask for a translation to English. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this should be translated as:

"A doctor should not accept gifts..." it is not about some certain person who had not taken an action, it is about an ethic rule any doctor should follow.

Be warned, this Stack is not about questions on translations **to** English, but as far as you are actually asking about the correctness of initial form, then well, first form is correct.

Comment: If you start with the English with "would" and translate into Russian is the first form with не должен  still correct?   Can you explain why?

Comment: Sorry, I don't actually understand what are you asking about:( But once again I repeat that translations from English are not discussed here.

Answer (score 1):

`Доктор не станет брать подарков у бедных`
In fact, `would/would not` can be translated in several ways, but I believe that it means `will not` in this example.

Comment: Please, edit the answer in order to make it more informative. Sentence, consisting of two variants and conclusion "I'm not sure" is not a good answer.